# loop not going to next page

Tags: python, html, lxml

I just made a python script that goes to a lawyers profile to scrape their details. It is working fine for first page but the loop is not going to second page. The script is scraping data from first page only. I want to scrape all pages. Please help me I am new to python.

Here is the code:

```
import requests

from lxml import html

root_url = 'http://lawyerlist.com.au/'

def get_page_urls(): 
  for no in ('1','2'):  
    page = requests.get('http://lawyerlist.com.au/lawyers.aspx?city=Sydney&Page=' + no)   
    tree = html.fromstring(page.text)
    return (tree.xpath('//td/a/@href'))

for li in (get_page_urls()):
  pag=requests.get(root_url + li) 
  doc = html.fromstring(pag.text)
  for name in doc.xpath('//tr/td/h1/text()'):
    print(name)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `get_page_urls` function only returns the urls of the first page because of the return statement in the for loop. Use a yield statement to turn the function into a generator and then iterate over each page of urls like so:

```
import requests

from lxml import html

root_url = 'http://lawyerlist.com.au/'

def get_page_urls(): 
  for no in ('1','2'):  
    page = requests.get('http://lawyerlist.com.au/lawyers.aspx?city=Sydney&Page=' + no)   
    tree = html.fromstring(page.text)
    yield tree.xpath('//td/a/@href')

for page_of_urls in get_page_urls():
  for li in page_of_urls:
    pag=requests.get(root_url + li) 
    doc = html.fromstring(pag.text)
    for name in doc.xpath('//tr/td/h1/text()'):
      print(name)
```

Comment: Today I learned something new about python.Thank you again.sir would you please recommend me any online python tutorial ebook that would be good for beginners like me.

Comment: @user3891081 Check out Zed Shaw's learn python the hardway, the html version is free to read online [link](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the return in the `for no in ('1', '2'):`

Once it hits this return, it will stop running the loop and exit the function.  You could append `tree.xpath('//td/a/@href')` to a list, and then outside of the for loop return the list.

something like:

```
def get_page_urls():
  all_trees = []
  for no in ('1','2'):  
    page = requests.get('http://lawyerlist.com.au/lawyers.aspx?city=Sydney&Page=' + no)   
    tree = html.fromstring(page.text)
    all_trees.append(tree.xpath('//td/a/@href'))
  return all_trees
```